# How to Output Values Using Max or Greatest?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This is the data given:

```
CusNAME   CusMileage 
-------   ---------
  Bob         2500    
  Lee         5      
  Ashley      5000
```

Customers can only use 2000 miles at a time for rewards. The **output** should be:

```
CusNAME   CusMileage 
-------   ---------
  Bob         2000    
  Lee         5      
  Ashley      2000
```

Should I use the max function?

`SELECT CusNAME, MAX(CusMileage) <= 2000;`

or

```
SELECT CusNAME, Greatest(CusMileage) <= 2000;
```

Comment: I think u have to use MAX function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [LEAST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions075.htm) function might be the best in this case

```
SELECT CusNAME, Least(CusMileage, 2000)
FROM table1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2715/1

```
| CusNAME | Least(CusMileage, 2000) |
|---------|-------------------------|
|     Bob |                    2000 |
|     Lee |                       5 |
|  Ashley |                    2000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

select cusName, case when CusMileage >= 2000 then 2000 else CusMileage end as CusMileageResponse from table1